# Flutter app export-import db to the downloads folder

Tags: flutter, sqflite

there's pretty usual case: I've created an app which uses SQLite as storage. Now I want to add some backup functionality. What is the proper way to do this?

I want to backup .db file and put it's copy to a `Downloads` folder. Later I'll need to import that file and all data from the file (but not overwrite new data).

I tried to google some solutions, but nothing was found. For db connection I'm using `sqflite`, but haven't found any export-import functionality there. Any ideas how could I do this?